# Find files with multiple matches of a pattern in the filename in linux

Tags: regex, shell, find, filenames

I'm trying to `find` multiple files with 40 hexadecimal digits. I can use

```
ls -l | grep '[0-9A-F]\{40\}'
```

And see the files I want to see them but I want to use `find` for this for the sake of the challenge. I tried:

```
find . -regextype grep -regex '[0-9A-F]\{40\}'
```

It doesn't work. I would be happy to understand this matter.

Bonus question: How this can be done with shell regular expressions like this: `ls -l [0-9A-F]{40}`?